# Entity Framework Core Add Migration gives Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'connectionString')

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first

I'm new to .NET Core and working through an Udemy class. I'm trying to enable migrations to do code-first but I keep getting an error

> Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'connectionString')

I've done some researching and it seems as though most of the time it's misspelling of `ConnectionStrings` in the `appsetttings.json` file. However, I've looked all over mine and tried several copy/paste to make sure I have the correct spellings. Either it's something else or I've looked at this so much I'm overlooking something.

Appsettings.json

```
{
    "ConnectionStings": {
        "DbConnection": "Server=DAVIDPC\\SQLEXPRESS01;Database=dotnet-rpg;Trusted_Connection=true;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;"
    },
    "Logging": {
        "LogLevel": {
            "Default": "Information",
            "Microsoft": "Warning",
            "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
        }
    },
    "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

Startup.cs

```
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
{
    Configuration = configuration;
}

public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(x => x.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DbConnection")));
    services.AddControllers();
    services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Startup));
    services.AddScoped<ICharacterService, CharacterService>();
}
```

Comment: Can you make the connection string like this. Data Source=your server;Initial Catalog=DBNAme;User ID=id;Password=fx4me-

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your example you misspelled **ConnectionStrings**

```
 {
        "ConnectionStrings": {
            "DbConnection": "Server=DAVIDPC\\SQLEXPRESS01;Database=dotnet-rpg;Trusted_Connection=true;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;"
        },
        "Logging": {
            "LogLevel": {
                "Default": "Information",
                "Microsoft": "Warning",
                "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
            }
        },
        "AllowedHosts": "*"
    }
```

Comment: I swear I looked over that so many times. I guess because it was late at night. Going forward I'll have this in a OneNote so I can just copy/paste to avoid that kind of issue.

Answer (score 0):

Looks good with app settings and configure service method. 
try this

```
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DbContext": "Data Source=(LocalDb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=dotnet-rpg;Integrated Security=SSPI; MultipleActiveResultSets=true;",
    "Logging": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Information",
        "Microsoft": "Warning",
        "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
      }
    }
  }
```

the difference is that the connection string doesn't have "Data Source"

In configureService

```
services.AddDbContextPool<DataContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DbContext"))
            );
```

Please let me know if this resolved your issue.

Below two reference link has implementation details.

[Implement create, read, update, and delete functionalities using Entity Framework Core](https://karthiktechblog.com/microsoft-azure/implement-curd-functionalities-in-aspnetcore-using-entity-framework-core)

[Configure Azure SQL relational database using vs 2019](https://karthiktechblog.com/microsoft-azure/configure-azure-sql-database-and-migrate-changes-using-dotnet-cli)

Comment: My initial connection string had the "Data Source" and all of that info like you have. I just changed it around while I was researching trying to find the problem. I'll probably go back to this connection string info since that is the way Visual Studio created it for me.